# Prestashop 1.7 hook for product details page

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am creating a custom module in prestashop 1.7. In that module I want to show some custom content block in the product details page. So the custom content should show only in the product details page. I have used these hooks but they are not working anymore.

- hookExtraRight
- hookExtraLeft
- HookProductTabs
- hookProductTabsContent

These hooks only work in Prestashop 1.6 . What are the hooks that can be used in Prestashop 1.7 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following mentioned Hook to display Custom Content block on product detail page :

1. displayProductButtons - only for Prestashop 1.7.0
2. displayProductAdditionalInfo- for Prestashop 1.7.1.x